Using DialTLSContext to disable cert verification for proxy server
I made a Golang program that makes a connection to HTTPS server (eg. https://google.com) via a HTTPS proxy. But I wanted to so disable cert verification for just proxy server - Disable TLS cert verification for proxy server in Golang.
I was pointed to this question that asked the same exact thing. I tested it and it's working as expected.
The solution provided there is -

You can set you client Transport to use both Transport.TLSClientConfig and Transport.DialTLSContext. In this case TLSClientConfig should be used for connections to destination HTTPS server and DialTLSContext - for connection to your HTTPS proxy.

Then, I read the documentation for DialTLSContext and got confused. The doc says the following:

    // DialTLSContext specifies an optional dial function for creating
    // TLS connections for non-proxied HTTPS requests.
    //
    // If DialTLSContext is nil (and the deprecated DialTLS below is also nil),
    // DialContext and TLSClientConfig are used.
    //
    // If DialTLSContext is set, the Dial and DialContext hooks are not used for HTTPS
    // requests and the TLSClientConfig and TLSHandshakeTimeout
    // are ignored. The returned net.Conn is assumed to already be
    // past the TLS handshake.
    DialTLSContext func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)

So, I have the following questions:

Doc says - DialTLSContext specifies an optional dial function for creating
TLS connections for non-proxied HTTPS requests, but the answer suggests DialTLSContext is used for connection to your HTTPS proxy.
Doc also mentions that the TLSClientConfig are ignored when DialTLSContext is set but the answer mentions we could use both of them (which is correct because the solution is working fine

Thanks.

Ok, so here is my interpretation after reading the answer and doc multiple times:
My setup is like this:
A (client) ---- B (Proxy server) --- C (Google server)
Here, as mentioned above A <-> B traffic does TLS, and when CONNECT succeeds A <-> C will also so end-to-end TLS.
The solution provided in the link -
c.Client = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            // configs for destination server or nil to use defaults
        },
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(insecureproxy),
        DialTLSContext: func(_ context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return tls.Dial(network, addr, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
        },
    },
}

Since A <-> B is a direct connection (no proxy server is between A and B), as doc mentions, DialTLSContext is used and TLSClientConfig
is ignored.
Now, there is another end-to-end TLS that happens between A <--> C (via B). This this is a proxied HTTPS request, hence DialTLSContext is ignored this time and TLSClientConfig is used for destination server.
